# Issue: VS2005 not working with VSTO for Office 2007

Tags: visual-studio-2005, vsto

Here at work I have Visual Studio 2005 and Office 2007 installed.  I'm trying to install the VSTO package to create a templated Word Document project.  I installed the VSTO package via this link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=8315654b-a5ae-4108-b7fc-186402563f2b#filelist

Whenever I create a new Word Template Office Project I receive an error message informing me that Office 2003 is not installed.  It clearly states the package is for office 2003 and office 2007.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Here's the error message:  http:// i34.tinypic.com/2a4wg9u.png

Answer (score 1):

You've got the wrong download. Office Second Edition is Office 2003.

You want this one for Office 2007

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5E86CAB3-6FD6-4955-B979-E1676DB6B3CB&displaylang=en